# addEventListener just implements the function without listening

Tags: javascript

I use this code to start a game, but for some reasons the startGame() is fired immediately when the page is loaded without me clicking anything.

```
window.onload = function() {
    id("start-btn").addEventListener("mousedown", startGame());
}
```

Comment: _“for some reasons the startGame() is fired immediately”_ — you literally typed `startGame()`. What did you expect to happen otherwise? Duplicate of [addEventListener in Javascript triggers the click event automatically](/q/11489734/4642212).

Comment: Just remove parentheses and wirite the function name without anything else

Comment: thank you seb, remove the parentheses and it works finely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to call the function along with the event itself. From `startgame()`, remove the parantheses.

```
window.onload = function() {
id("start-btn").addEventListener("mousedown", startGame);
```

}

This must work fine, to my expectation.